org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'bookDao' defined in file
I just started to learn some springboot project, here is a problem which i have no idea how to solve it and i do not even know what's happenning.
BookDao.java
package com.carl.dao;

import com.baomidou.mybatisplus.core.mapper.BaseMapper;
import com.carl.domain.Book;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

@Mapper
public interface BookDao extends BaseMapper<Book> {
}

Book.java
package com.carl.domain;

import lombok.Data;
 
@Data
public class Book  {
    private Integer id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}

SSMPApplication.java
package com.carl;

import org.mybatis.spring.annotation.MapperScan;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.carl.dao")
public class SSMPApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SSMPApplication.class, args);
    }
}

application.yml
server:
  port: 8888

spring:
  datasource:
    druid:
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8
      username: root
      password: root
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

mybatis-plus:
  global-config:
    db-config:
      id-type: auto
  configuration:
    log-impl: org.apache.ibatis.logging.commons.JakartaCommonsLoggingImpl
  mapper-locations: classpath*:mapper/*.xml
  type-aliases-package: com.carl.domain

BookDaoTestCase.java
package com.carl.dao;

import com.carl.domain.Book;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
public class BookDaoTestCase {

    @Autowired
    private BookDao bookDao;

    @Test
    void getBookById() {
        System.out.println(bookDao.selectById(1));
    }

    @Test
    void getAllBooks() {
        System.out.println(bookDao.selectList(null));
    }

    @Test
    void updateBookById() {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setId(10);
        book.setType("a");
        book.setName("a");
        book.setDescription("a");
        System.out.println(bookDao.updateById(book));
    }

    @Test
    void deleteBookById() {
        System.out.println(bookDao.deleteById(0));
    }

    @Test
    void addNewBook() {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setType("b");
        book.setName("b");
        book.setDescription("b");
        System.out.println(bookDao.insert(book));
    }

}

That's pretty much all I have right now, and i get the wrong situations below
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@748d2277 testClass = com.carl.dao.BookDaoTestCase, locations = [], classes = [com.carl.SSMPApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceDescriptors = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@41e1e210, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@1ba9117e, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@10163d6, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactor.netty.DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerFactory$DisableReactorResourceFactoryGlobalResourcesContextCustomizerCustomizer@793be5ca, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizer@fa49800, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@ee5424e7], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:180)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'bookDao' defined in file [/Users/zhanghuanjin/Documents/Projects/Springboot/springboot_01_01_quickstart/target/classes/com/carl/dao/BookDao.class]: Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getType(AbstractBeanFactory.java:743)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAnnotationOnBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.detect(AnnotationDependsOnDatabaseInitializationDetector.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor.detectDependsOnInitializationBeanNames(DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.dependency.DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer$DependsOnDatabaseInitializationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(DatabaseInitializationDependencyConfigurer.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:363)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:789)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152)

Very confused about what's going on, please make comment if you know anything.
I'm trying to figure what causes the problem and how to fix it

Please add the full stacktrace, it feels like it is cut off and thus missing information.

Could be a duplicate of Invalid value type for attribute 'factoryBeanObjectType': java.lang.String in Spring v6.1
Did you try to add this in your pom.xml ?
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>

